# Unchecked read permissions for folder to password protect but now get 500(Internal Server Error)

Tags: web-hosting, godaddy, iis, windows, http-code-500

I unchecked the read permissions for a folder I have on a Godaddy Windows shared host that I want password protected and it worked first time but since going back I get 500 (Internal Server) Error. Thought it might be cache something so tried hard refresh but nothing.

Answer (score 1):

In the GoDaddy Help Center: [Password Protecting Web Directories on a Windows Hosting Account](http://help.godaddy.com/topic/173/article/3977)

Comment: Been there, done that. Maybe I should have been more explicit in the title.

Comment: @Pathfinder If you've already followed the host's own instructions(And yes, you should edit your question to point that out.), then it's probably time to talk to support.

Answer (score 0):

to password protect a directory on godaddy, don't change the permissions. go to godaddy hosting ftp file manager and select the folder and click on protect. Click on the password protection tab and put a password.

BTW you need an HTACCESS and HTPASSWD file rather than changing permissions. GoDaddy will create it for you when you select the password protection option.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I remember HTACCESS and HTPASSWD from my linux days. Does Godaddy use them for Windows accounts? I click on folder and do not see a protect option.